# Insert camera inside UIViewController as a subview

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewcontroller` with a subView of a box for a photo, i need to insert the camera inside of this box, i have searched over the web and i have found that `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`

> AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer =
>   [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
>
> [self.view.layer addSublayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer];

and `UIImagePickerController`

> self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
>
> [self.view addSubview:self.picker.view];

could help, but i cant achieve to put the camera inside the box, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Checkout this sample implementation of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: https://github.com/colbertw08/preview-camera

Comment: You want to go with the first option (AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer), and not with UIImagePickerController (which is meant to be used as a full-screen modal view controller, and will behave inconsistently when its view is put inside a frame).